# What proofs are based/use/depend on existance convex hull or convex envelope?

Tags: convex-analysis

I wonder if there are any is at least one proof of any mathmatical fact that would use [convex hull or convex envelope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) as mathmatical object valuable for that proof?

Comment: [Gauss-Lucas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss-Lucas_theorem)?

Comment: Also [Newton polygon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_polygon), but the Wikpedia article does not do it justice. See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/15703/newton-and-newton-polygon.